# Swift Extension exception Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, swift-extensions, exc-bad-instruction

I have tried to do an extension to NSDate. What I wanted is a flag indicating if the NSDate has to be removed later

So I have tried this in playground

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

var str = "Hello, playground"



extension NSDate {
    private struct RemovalInformation {
        static var removed: Bool = false
    }
    var removed: Bool {
        get {
            return (objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &RemovalInformation.removed) as! Bool)
        }
        set(newValue) {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &RemovalInformation.removed, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
        }
    }
}

let date = NSDate()
print( "The Date is: \(date)")

if(date.removed == true) {
    print ("removed")
}
```

But line `if(date.removed == true)` produces an error I have no clue how to deal with: "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`objc_getAssociatedObject` returns `nil` if no object has been associated
to the `NSDate`, and then the forced cast `as! Bool` crashes.
(It would also crash if an associated object has been set, but its
value is not convertible to `Bool`.)

You can make the property optional:

```
var removed: Bool? {
    get {
        return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &RemovalInformation.removed) as? Bool
    }
    set(newValue) {
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &RemovalInformation.removed, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
    }
}
```

or provide a default value, e.g. using the nil-coalescing operator `??`:

```
var removed: Bool {
    get {
        return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &RemovalInformation.removed) as? Bool ?? false
    }
    set(newValue) {
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &RemovalInformation.removed, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
    }
}
```

Note that `&RemovalInformation.removed` only serves as a memory address
identifying the associated object uniquely. The contents of that
static property and its type is  irrelevant and not used at all. In particular, the object association is not "initialized" with the value of that property.

Comment: Thanks buddy, you made my day. I thought it could be a tiny thing but the whole expression was too new to me as I could fully understand. With what you have mentioned I definitely understand the whole thing a bit more. Thanks man.